# Probability of selecting one of multiple sets of distinct items

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

Here is the problem I am having:

You have a set of items; let's say colored stones.  There are 40 stones.  3 Blue, 3 Red, 3 Green, 3 White, 3 Yellow, 3 Purple, 3 Orange, 1 Black, 18 Grey.  Without looking, you select 6 stones from the set.

There are a number of desirable pairs: Blue and Red, Blue and White, Yellow and Purple, Yellow and Orange, Green and Black (these are arbitrary, for the problems I will be solving, the number of colors that are not Grey may be more or less than 8, but the important part is that not every pair is necessarily of stone colors where there are 3 stones of each color).

1) How do I find the probability of selecting any particular desirable pair, such as Blue and Red (in other words, out of the 6 stones, at least 1 should be Blue and at least 1 should be Red)?

My first thoughts are combinatorics, such as #2 from [Probability of selecting different kinds of items from a set of items](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441380/probability-of-selecting-different-kinds-of-items-from-a-set-of-items), but I don't particularly care which Blue stone I select out of all my Blue stones, and the results don't agree with previous problems of this kind solved by others (unfortunately without showing their work).

2) How do I find the probability of selecting at least 1 desirable pair from a list of desirable pairs (in other words, if my list of desirable pairs is specified above, what is the probability of having at least 1 in my set of 6 stones)?

I am looking for a mathematical way of doing this, rather than brute-forcing it with nested for-loops.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From the multiset, $S = \{\mathrm{Blue}^3, \mathrm{Red}^3, \mathrm{Green}^3, \mathrm{White}^3, \mathrm{Yellow}^3, \mathrm{Orange}^3, \mathrm{blacK}^1, \mathrm{grEy}^{18}\}$

Select 6 stones, find $P(B \geq 1, R \geq 1)$.

$P(B \geq 1, R \geq 1) = P(B = 1, R \geq 1) + P(B = 2, R \geq 1) + P(B = 3, R \geq 1) \\ \quad = P(B=1)P(R\geq1 \mid B=1) +P(B=2)P(R\geq1 \mid B=2)+P(B=3)P(R\geq 1 \mid B=3) \\ \quad = \frac{{3\choose 1}\left({3\choose 1}{24\choose 4}+{3\choose 2}{24\choose 3}+{3\choose 3}{24\choose 2}\right) + {3\choose 2}\left({3\choose 1}{24\choose 3}+{3\choose 2}{24\choose 2}+{3\choose 3}{24\choose 1}\right) + {3\choose 3}\left({3\choose 1}{24\choose 2}+{3\choose 2}{24\choose 1}+{3\choose 3}{24\choose 0}\right)}{30\choose 6} \\ = \frac{3!^2 24!^2 6!}{30!}\left(\frac{1}{2!^2 4!20!}+\frac{1}{2!^2 3!21!}+\frac{1}{2!^2 3!22!}+ \frac{1}{2!^2 3!21!}+\frac{1}{2!^3 22!}+\frac{1}{3!^2 23!}+ \frac{1}{3! 2!^2 22!}+\frac{1}{3! 2! 23!}+\frac{1}{3!^2 24!}\right)$

Comment: Multiset is missing Purple and I think the denominator should be 40 choose 6, but I understand the basic principle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing this. To make things simpler, let's call the label the colors $1$ through $n$, and let's say you have $c_{i}$ stones of color $i$ (so in your example, $n = 9$). Let $C = \sum_{i} c_{i}$ be the total number of stones, and let's say you choose $m$ stones from this set.

For **question 1**, without loss of generality let's say the desirable pair consists of colors 1 and 2. Instead of directly computing the probability that you select this desirable pair, let's compute the probability that you don't select this desirable pair. How can this happen? Well, either you don't select any items of color 1, or you don't select any items of color 2. The probability you don't select any items of color 1 is just

$$p_{1} = \dfrac{\binom{C-c_{1}}{m}}{\binom{C}{m}}$$

Likewise, the probability you don't select any items of color 2 is just

$$p_{2} = \dfrac{\binom{C-c_{2}}{m}}{\binom{C}{m}}$$

But note that it's possible that we don't select any items of color 1 and don't select any items of color 2. Since we count these cases in both $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$, we count these cases twice. This occurs with probability

$$p_{12} = \dfrac{\binom{C-c_{1}-c_{2}}{m}}{\binom{C}{m}}$$

The probability we don't select this desirable pair is therefore $p_{1} + p_{2} - p_{12}$, so the probability that we do is

$$p = 1 - (p_1 + p_2 - p_{12}) = \dfrac{\binom{C}{m} - \binom{C-c_{1}}{m} - \binom{C-c_{2}}{m} + \binom{C-c_1-c_2}{m}}{\binom{C}{m}}$$

**Question 2** is a bit trickier, and I don't know of any reasonably closed form solution (for good reason; see below). Here's one mostly combinatorial way to do this, similar to the approach for question 1.

First, for any subset $S$ of the colors from $1$ to $n$, let $A_{S}$ be the number of selections of $n$ stones that only use colors from the set $S$. We can compute $A_{S}$ for each $S$ combinatorially by

$$A_{S} = \binom{\sum_{i\in S}c_{i}}{m}$$

Now, let $B_{S}$ be the number of selections of $n$ stones that only use colors from the set $S$, but in addition use each color at least once. By the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion, we can see that we can compute each $B_{S}$ by

$$B_{S} = \sum_{S' \subseteq S} (-1)^{|S|-|S'|}A_{S}$$

Finally, let $\mathcal{D}$ be the collection of subsets $S$ of colors that contain a desirable pair. It's clear then that the total number of selections that contain a desirable pair is equal to

$$B = \sum_{S \in \mathcal{D}} B_{S}$$

and the probability of drawing a desirable pair is therefore just

$$\dfrac{B}{\binom{C}{m}}$$

Since there are $2^{n}$ different possible subsets $S$, computing all the coefficients $B_{S}$ and $A_{S}$ takes time exponential in $n$, so it's natural to ask if there's a more efficient way. Unfortunately (or fortunately?) if you do find a general method for this problem that takes time polynomial in $n$, then you'll have shown that $P = NP$ (more specifically, you'll have shown that $P = \#P$).

To see this, let's consider the case where we have exactly one stone of each color (so $C=n$). Note that if we can solve this problem in polynomial time, we can also count the total number of subsets (not necessarily of size $m$) of these $n$ stones that contain a desirable pair (we can do this just by summing over $m$). This number is equal to $|\mathcal{D}|$.

But now, note that computing $2^{n} - |\mathcal{D}|$ (the number of subsets without a desirable pair) is equivalent to solving a general problem in $\#MONOTONE-2SAT$, where the variables are colors, and for each desired pair of colors $x_{i}$ and $x_{j}$ we have the clause $(\bar{x}_{i} \vee \bar{x}_{j})$, representing that either we don't pick color $i$ or we don't pick color $j$. Since $\#MONOTONE-2SAT$ is $\#P$-complete, it follows that if we can compute $|\mathcal{D}|$ in polynomial time, $\#P = P$ and therefore $P=NP$.

(Of course, since in your example $n$ is just $9$, this method is definitely efficient enough to solve your example. For larger $n$, if you don't need the exact probability, you might also be fine with just running a Monte Carlo simulation to estimate this probability).